# \langle \rangle with punctuation

Tags: punctuation, brackets

Is there a way to write

```
\langle some text \rangle
```

where the "some text" will be written with punctuation and will not contain any math symbols ? Maybe there is a different command for this bracket for use in a general text, but I didn't find one which would work.

Comment: What about `$\langle$ some text $\rangle$`? Or better yet, depending on the use, write a macro: `\newcommand{\sometext}[1]{\text{$\langle$~#1~$\rangle$}}` (add `\usepackage{amsmath}` to your document preamble). This allows you to use `\sometext{some text}` in math mode or regular text mode.

Comment: `\newcommand{\textinbrackets}[1]{\ensuremath{\langle}#1\ensuremath{\rangle}
}%` for example with `\textinbrackets{Hello World!}`

Comment: Thanks, that helped, I must have had some kind of a typing error earlier, because `$\langle$ some text $\rangle$` didn't work for some reason and now it does.

Comment: The `textcomp` package provides `\textlangle` and `\textrangle`.

Comment: Use `amsmath` and use `$\left\langle\text{stuff}\right\rangle$`. The proposed solutions that use `$\langle$` and `$\rangle$ are not ideal because they disable LaTeX's ability to match pairs of delimiters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you want angle brackets or guillemet quotes:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

This $\langle$one, two three$\rangle$

or

This \guilsinglleft one, two three\guilsinglright

\end{document}
```

Comment: I wanted angle brackets, but thanks for the guillemet quotes, I'll need them too.

Answer (score 9):

since this wasn't specifically a latex question, here's my favorite method.

```
\def\<#1>{$\langle$\ignorespaces#1\unskip$\rangle$}

\<some text>  \< some text >
```

good for "meta" notation, if this alternate form is used (does require latex):

```
\def\<#1>{$\langle$\textit{\ignorespaces#1\unskip}$\rangle$}
```

Comment: This deserves more votes....